# Ansible 2 dictionaries intersection

Tags: ansible

on Ansible 2.2 I have

```
all_subnets:
id   | subnet         | mask | sectionId 
-----+----------------+------+-----------
4831 | 172.31.0.0     | 16   | 19        
4832 | 192.168.0.0    | 24   | 19        
4858 | 192.168.248.0  | 21   | 19        
4859 | 192.168.248.0  | 27   | 19        
4860 | 192.168.248.32 | 28   | 19
```

and another json list containing the expected subnets

```
my_subnets:
  - subnet: "192.168.0.0"
    mask: "24"
  - subnet: "192.168.248.32"
    mask: "28"
```

Now, I would like to intersect the two lists:

```
id   | subnet         | mask | sectionId 
-----+----------------+------+-----------
4832 | 192.168.0.0    | 24   | 19        
4860 | 192.168.248.32 | 28   | 19
```

How can I achieve this?

Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this I prefer to refactor the top-level "database" value to a dictionary (presumably, keyed by ID). This format makes it easy to access a subset of values based on their IDs or other attributes, or to access the entire set of values.

This is also consistent with Ansible's mantra to "keep things simple", minimizing the need for complications like intersections and matching.

For example:

```
---
all_subnets:
  4831: { id: 4831, subnet: "172.31.0.0",     mask: 16, sectionId: 19, }
  4832: { id: 4832, subnet: "192.168.0.0",    mask: 24, sectionId: 19, }
  4858: { id: 4858, subnet: "192.168.248.0",  mask: 21, sectionId: 19, }
  4859: { id: 4859, subnet: "192.168.248.0",  mask: 27, sectionId: 19, }
  4860: { id: 4860, subnet: "192.168.248.32", mask: 28, sectionId: 19, }

# Your use-case
my_subnets: ["{{ all_subnets[4832] }}", "{{ all_subnets[4860] }}"]

# Getting subnets matching a value
my_subnets: "{{ all_subnets | selectattr('subnet', 'equalto', '192.168.248.0') | list }}"

# Getting all subnets
my_subnets: "{{ all_subnets.values() }}"
```